# What methods are available to do 2D animation over 3D model?

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, grease-pencil, 2d

I want to place 2D animation over 3D mesh, to animate eyes for instance. I do not want to use 3D eye globes because this approach limits the available emotions (I cannot display star-shaped eyes or full of tears, as example). The same thing with eyebrows and mouth.

My first idea was to use UV-maps and swap them during the animation. The main disadvantage of this technique is that the animation will not be smooth. Or I have to draw all the motion phases by hands.

What techniques are available for doing 2D animation in blender?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: Related https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk ... as you can see your Q is on the way to be closed as opinion based. Already you know 2D over 3D is possible ... Please change title to something more specific ... also some reference image or gif would be helpful.

Comment: In newer versions of Blender you can animate 2D using the Grease Pencil.  Check out tutorials on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your animations with curves in blender naturally, render them in 2D then use them as an animated texture.

loading an mp4 in an image node automagically makes it a video:
[image: loading an mp4 in an image node automagically makes it a video]

You could then either keyframe the offset of use a driver and keyframe an empty as shown in the picture

Sadly Shader Nodes are quite complicated to get advanced math implemented. I'm sure you could make all your Bezier curves in shader math but I don't know why wou would want to.